# Beginner Java - Cannot Find Symbol Errors?

Tags: java

I've been trying to figure out why this basic java program wont run. I get about 7 cannot find symbol errors. Any help would be much appreciated. I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong.

The program is just some basic calculations that prompt for some input and output data that show what a speeder's fine would be.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Lab1 {
public static void main (String args[]) {

    // Create a scanner to read from keyboard
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("\nEnter Driver's FIRST Name.");
    String firstName = kbd.next();

    System.out.print("\nEnter Driver's LAST Name.");
    String lastName = kbd.next();

    System.out.print("\nEnter Driver's Age.");
    int age = Integer.parseInt(kbd.next());

    System.out.print("\nEnter the Speed Limit.");
    int speedLimit = Integer.parseInt(kbd.next());

    System.out.print("\nEnter Driver's Actual Speed");
    int actualSpeed = Integer.parseInt(kbd.next());

    System.out.print("\nDid violation occur in construction zone? (yes/no)");
    String constructionZone = kbd.next();

    int speedDifference = (actualSpeed - speedLimit);



    if (speedDifference <= 5) {
        int baseFine = 0;
    }
    else if(speedDifference >= 20) {
        int baseFine = (speedDifference / 5) * 50;
    }
    else {
        int baseFine = (speedDifference / 5) * 30;
    }



    if(constructionZone.equals("yes")) {
        int constructionFine = 10;
    }
    else {
        int constructionFine = 0;
    }



    if(age <= 21 && speedDifference >= 20) {
        int underageFine = 300;
    }
    else {
        int underageFine = 0;
    }



    int totalFine = baseFine + constructionFine + underageFine;

    System.out.println("Last Name: " + lastName);
    System.out.println("First Name: " + firstName);
    System.out.println("Driver Age: " + age);
    System.out.println("Speed Limit: " + speedLimit);
    System.out.println("Actual Speed: " + actualSpeed);
    System.out.println("MPH Over Limit: " + speedDifference);
    System.out.println("Base Fine: $" + baseFine);
    System.out.println("Construction Zone Fine: $" + constructionFine);
    System.out.println("Underage Fine: $" + underageFine);
    System.out.println("Total Fine: $" + totalFine);

}
}
```

Comment: And doesn't your compiler/IDE point the location of the errors ?

Comment: declare baseFine, constructionFine and underageFine first

Answer (score 5):

Your variables `baseFine`, `constructionFine` and `underageFine` are defined within the scope of `if` statements. Declare them outside of that scope so that they are visible in the scope of the `main` method. For example

```
int baseFine = 0;
if (speedDifference <= 5) {
     baseFine = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`baseFine` ,`constructionFine` ,`underageFine` These 3 variables are not declared properly. You have declared these three within a local scope. But outside of the scope it can not be recognized. 
So declare them as class members.

**WHAT IS VARIABLE SCOPE**

as you are beginner of java so I think you better know about what variable scope is.

The scope of a variable is the part of the program over which the variable name can be referenced.

You can declare variables in several different places:

- In a class body as class fields.
- As parameters of a method or constructor.
- In a method's body or a constructor's body.
- Within a statement block, such as inside a while or for block.

Variable scope refers to the accessibility of a variable. You neither can refer to a variable before its declaration nor you can use them outside the scope

Answer (score 0):

You got variable scoping issues

underageFine , constructionFine and baseFine  need to be defined outside of the if/elso to be accessible by the rest of the method.